# dropdown menu - toggling menu icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quick question…

When a user clicks on a navigation menu that says “expand_more” a dropdown appears and “expand_less” displays and replaces “expand_more”.

If a user clicks on another menu that says “expand_more” the previous dropdown menu closes but “expand_less” still displays. I need this to display “expand_more”.

With the code I currently have how do I get the previous dropdown menu to display “expand_more”?

Side Note: expand_more and expand_less are Google font icons.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

JS

```
$(".navigationV1 ul.top-level-menu .label").on("click", handleNavClick);

function handleNavClick() {
  const isActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
  if (isActive) {
    $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  } else {
    // Close already opened menus
    $(".active").removeClass("active").siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideUp();
    // Toggle top nav links
    $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  }
}

$(".navigationV1 .top-level-menu .label").on("click", function () {
  // Flip Arrow
  $(this).find(".material-symbols-outlined").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

CSS

```
.active {
  background-color: #666;
}

.drop-down-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigationV1 top-level-menu label">

  <div class="descendant-links-container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 1
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon">expand_more</span>
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon hide">expand_less</span>

        </a>

        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 2</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 3
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon">expand_more</span>
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon hide">expand_less</span>

        </a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 2
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you close the already opened menus, you need to toggle `hide` class for `.material-symbols-outlined` for them. Like this:

```
  else {
    // Switch icon for opened menus
    $(".active").find(".material-symbols-outlined").toggleClass("hide");
    // Close already opened menus
    $(".active").removeClass("active").siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideUp();
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add expand-more and expand-less class to your html spans. Make sure to change in all menu items.

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon expand-more">expand_more</span>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined expand-icon expand-less hide">expand_less</span>
```

and then change your js function to this.

```
 function handleNavClick() {
  const isActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
    //below two lines will reset the class state
  $('.expand-more').removeClass('hide');
  $('.expand-less').addClass('hide');
        
  if (isActive) {
    $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).find(".expand-more").removeClass("hide");     
    $(this).find(".expand-less").addClass("hide");  
  } else {
    // Close already opened menus
    $(".active").removeClass("active").siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideUp();
    // Toggle top nav links
    $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).find(".expand-more").addClass("hide");      
    $(this).find(".expand-less").removeClass("hide");
  }
}
```

Second click handler is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That works however when a user clicks on the same menu item the icon stopped toggling.. how can I keep the toggling the same when a user clicks on the same menu item?

Comment: Updated my answer. please check again.

Comment: Perfect! thank you sir! worked like a charm! you are a JS ninja!